# python regex expression to match (first multipart or simple part) rar archive

Tags: python, regex

I would like match

- **first element in multipart** rar archive,

  `regex (.*.)part0*1.rar`

or

- **single part** rar archive,
  don't match string contains `^.*(part\d+).rar$`

I use this regex:

```
regex = r"(.*)(?:part0*1|.*[^(part\d+)])\.rar"
```

I 've got some issues:

- apps.rar *match* but apps2.rar *dont match and should*
- LA460.6.7.rar *dont match and should*
- apps.rar   should match in `group(1)="apps"` not `group(1)="app"`

[You can check snippet @regex101](https://regex101.com/r/j2gW0e/3/)

Could you find the error in the regex?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you sometimes match the last character is because the pattern `(.*)(?:part0*1|.*[^(part\d+)])\.rar` that you tried, first captures the whole line in capture group 1.

That capture group is followed by an alternation matching either `part0*1` or `.*[^(part\d+)]`

You can see that the lines that have *part* followed by a digit at the end are matched.

But, when there is no match for `part0*1` the next alternative is tried which is `.*[^(part\d+)]`.

The second alternative matches until the end of the string (where it already is), and then matches a **single character** of `[^(part\d+)]` because using the square brackets makes it a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) without a quantifier.

---

One option could be using a negative lookahead asserting that the string does not contain `part` followed by optional zeroes and either a char 2-9 and optional digits or `|` 1-9 and 1 or more digits.

```
^(?!.*part0*(?:[2-9]\d*|[1-9]\d+)\.rar)(.+)\.rar$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K7gkvN/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can search for filenames that "Either have word 'part' followed by 01/1 or don't have the word 'part' at all"

Please try below regex

```
(.*part0?1|^(?!.*part.*).*)\.rar
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/j2gW0e/6)